# jQuery keeps putting post data into URL

Tags: php, jquery, session, post

I'm having some trouble with Jquery as of late. I wanted to get a little more skillful with it and create a login form using Jquerys $.post method but I've hit a little snag.

For some reason When I click the button to submit, the data I want to post instead gets put into the URL of the current page I'm in. Furthermore, the Jquery will only work when this data is in the url.

I don't want to show the website visitors their username and password in the url. Why isn't it just posting the data as intended?

EDIT: IT seems even with all the changes i've made, I still need to submit the form twice for it to actually log me in.

// WHERE MY REQUEST IS MADE AND SENT

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $( "#loginbtn" ).click(function() {
            var u = $("#loginform input:text" ).val();
            var p = $("#loginform input:password" ).val();
            $.post( "http://www.gameandshame.com/auth/login.php", { username: u, password: p}).done(function( data ) {
            //alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
            location.href = "http://www.gameandshame.com/";
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

//DATA POSTED TO HERE

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("".$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/auth/class_loader.php");
echo "STARTING LOGIN";
    $login = new login();
    $login = $login->startLogin($_POST['username'],$_POST['password']);
?>
```

//END OF MY STARTLOGIN FUNCTION

```
    $_SESSION['t'] = $t;
    $_SESSION['u'] = $u;
    echo "SUCCESS";
    return;
```

// The Login Form

```
<form method="post" id="loginform">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="username" type="text" maxlength="24" placeholder="Username"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="password" type="password" maxlength="24" placeholder="Password"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input id="loginbtn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Go!" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

I'm honestly at a miss as to why it would stick the arguments in the URL. there seems to be no logical reason for it, even more .

NOTE: The "STARTING LOGIN" only gets returned when I try to login and all the form data is in the url. The login script isn't even ran if there is no data in the url. very weird... :S

Comment: Your form method is set to `GET` and you aren't preventing default behaviour of the form submit. Plus, you have a syntax error.

Comment: where do you use `u` and `p` variables. and where var `data` is set before its sending?

Comment: Ive added the html form I'm using and @Banzay var data isn't set as data to be sent, it's data that gets returned.

Comment: I've made those edits and now the login is working, but the data sent back is not displayed in the alert like I wanted it to be.

Comment: to prevent data to put in URL you need to use `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: Now check whether the submitted form (#testform) contains inputs named as `username` and `password`. or show here html code of form

Comment: @Banzay, the HTML of the form is in the question.

Comment: So OP: why are you doing this all via AJAX and on success send the user to another page? Why not just do it the normal way? Just post the form to the server without AJAX.

Comment: because I want to be able to have dynamic messages come back to the user without having to use a $_GET to pass error messages back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

In my form i had

```
<input id="loginbtn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Go!" />
```

when what I really needed to do was take out the submit from the button, and just grab the form details on-click. Because this `type="submit"` was still in there, it was posting the form normally, then attempting to post again from the JS, and as a result completely screwed up the ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems.

1. [NO LONGER VALID AFTER FULL CODE ADDED BY POSTER] Check your javascript console. None of your javascript is getting executed because you're msising a }); to close your .click.
2. [HTML CODE ADDED BY POSTER, STILL VALID POINT BUT NOT THE SOURCE OF ERROR] Without your html, I'm talking a guess here. But I see a problem with the absence of e.preventDefault() in your click event. If your button is type="submit", your form will submit normally.
3. Wrap everything in 
   $(document).ready(function(){ [ALL YOUR JS CODE ] });
   Otherwise jQuery tries to attach  your click event before the DOM is fully loaded.

Comment: The HTML is in the question.

Comment: Re-read, ive edited the question and made changes but its still broken.

Comment: Huh? This is all your javascript? Put everything in $(document.read(function(){   [all your code]    }); otherwise jQuery will try to attach your click event before the DOM is loaded and it won't do anything.

Comment: Then the bug is elsewhere. Check if you have anything that redirects with header('Location: ...') and appends everything in $_REQUEST. Most probably in the rest of the code of your login.php or your Login class

Comment: ok so I've managed to get it down  to where the ajax is sending the data which logs me in, but does not get any message back.

Comment: @herezy really don't know why I'm getting no response back to my script

Comment: Like I told you, the bug is elsewhere, probably a redirect in your login.php or your Login class. I copy/pasted all the code you posted on my server, only changed gameandchange.com, and it works fine. Your question is no longer about a small chunk of code. You're asking us to debug your whole site.